# Using correctly and cleanly onNewIntent() with setIntent()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities (A, B, C), 2 of which communicate with intents.
Here is the call order: A -> B -> C.
In activity B, I use `intent.putExtra("key", gameMode)` to start activity C.
When activity C is launched for the first time, there is no problem. But if C ends and I go back to B and change the game_mode, activity C always reads the very first intent.
I know this question will have been asked many times, but even if I try with `onNewIntent()` (with `setIntent(intent)` inside), or even with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, it doesn't change anything...
I guess (I'm sure...) I'm the one doing everything wrong, but I'm asking for your help for a complete and clear answer.
The goal being to update the intent (or at least its extras). Should I call the onNewIntent() method, or does Android do it on its own? etc

A huge thank you to the people who took the time to answer my question.

B activity :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuPrincipal.this, GameCard.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", gameMode);
        onNewIntent(intent);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

C activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    int gameMode;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        gameMode = extras.getInt("key", 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
    //default value : super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: What is the need of the keyword int in the putExtra()?

Comment: None
It was to show it was an integer. I removed it so.

Comment: can you give me **onBackPressed()** of activity C

Comment: extras.getInt("key"); try this instead of extras.getInt("key", 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *Ajay K S* who managed to find the answer:
By using extras.getInt("key"), the application works perfectly (you can read the last - and not only the first - intent without any problem).
Also, after testing, it is not necessary to call the onNewIntent(intent) method yourself to update the intent. It seems that Android does this itself.
Many thanks again!